# How to copy a row onto another excel worksheet if a column in it contains a specified value (of another column in the new sheet)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a randomised subset of numbers from a dataset that I have created a new column out of in a new datasheet. However, I need to copy the rows associated with the numbers from the column from the first datasheet into the second with a simple command. I have never used a VBA macro (if that is what it is called), but I was looking for any code that would be able to do this?

This was an example I found as an answer to another's question which I tried to modify with my very limited understanding of excel macros:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Copy_Cells()
    botRow = 100
    For i = botRow To 1 Step -1
      If Cells(i, 10).Value = B3:B186 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy
        Rows(i + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown
      End If
   Next i
End Sub
```

The error I got was about syntax. My problem is I don't understand what any of the code means. 
The original data is this:
[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuMJa.png)

This is what I want to input it into:
[Output wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqi3o.png)

Comment: Delete `Copy_Cells()` and use F8 to step through your code to find any other errors. You should run into an error on the `If` line. Are you trying to compare the value in `Cells(i, 10)` to the Sum of B3:B186?

Comment: No- I just realised I had incorrectly copied the code from the other answer, but I think I will try again. Thank you for the F8 tip. All I wanted to do was use the values in the 'output wanted' column B and find them in the first data file to copy the corresponding rows, if that makes sense

Comment: So, i take it that you have two worksheets and want to do a search, for each value in the destination worksheet column B, if found in the source worksheet column J, then copy the data in the found row of the source worksheet to the destination worksheet. You need to clarify the range of data you want to copy and where you want to paste the copied data. i.e. on the same destination row or inserted at the bottom of the worksheet, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I found a code that does exactly what I need it to do. I got it from another question on stackexchange, but thought I would post in case anyone else needs it.

```
Sub CopyYes()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Source As Worksheet
    Dim Target As Worksheet
    Dim Condition As Worksheet


    Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("source")
    Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("target")
    Set Condition = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("condition")

    j = 1    'This will start copying data to Target sheet at row 1
      For Each d In Condition.Range("A1:A86")
        For Each c In Source.Range("B2:B1893")
            If d = c Then
                Source.Rows(c.Row).Copy Target.Rows(j)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Next c
    Next d
End Sub
```